# Show a div when two different radio groups are selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to display a hidden div when two different radio buttons are selected; the radio buttons are in different groups and have different IDs. So the user will select a specific radio button to be shown this content. I am hoping to achieve this with JQuery.

I want the user to be presented with specific DIV content when they make specific radio selections but in different radio groups. Help!

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('[name="group1"], [name="group2"]').click(function(){
     if ($(this).attr("id") == "option1") && ($(this).attr("id") == "option2")
    {
       $('#test-display').show();
     } else {
       $("#test-display").hide();
       }
      });
   });
                           
  </script>
```

```html
  <div id="test-display" class="text-white" style="display:none ;">
   PLEASE SHOW ME
   </div>
   
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="group1" id="option1">
  </div>
  <div>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="option2">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just javascript without jQuery. (**edit:** I just meant to say that the same logic can be implemented in jQuery too if you only want to use that, but that's not necessary here.)

First you need to get those radio buttons you want when enabled should show the hidden div, add event listeners to them and check if both are enabled then change the css property of the hidden div.

Check my example of code below:

Say here when we select first radio button of group 1 and third radio button of group 2 then I should show the hidden div, otherwise I shouldn't.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on("change", buttonChanged);

function buttonChanged() {
  if ($("#group1_option1").is(':checked') && $("#group2_option3").is(':checked')) {
    $("#test-display").show();
  } else {
    $("#test-display").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test-display" class="text-white" style="display:none;">
  PLEASE SHOW ME
</div>

<div>
  <span>Group 1:</span>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_option1">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_option2">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Group 2:</span>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" id="group2_option1">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" id="group2_option2">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" id="group2_option3">
</div>
```

Comment: Looking for JQuery solution as most of my other code is Jquery; I will try this though!

Comment: @frankieseattle updated the js to use jquery, check this now

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in my environment, I copy and pasted it and no luck,

Comment: Also check ids of input and divs, they might be different from what I used. Because it was working on this sandbox so I think that might be the issue with jquery selecting elements.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
                                        $('input[type=radio]').click(function ()

Comment: For some reason I needed to add this to the beginning for it to work

Comment: A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you using `$(document).ready`. (source: jquery website)

Something like this might be happening, when we are trying to load the webpage, at the same time only we might we running our js code, but elements might not have been created by then so the query selector might have not selected any element so no event listeners have been attached to radio buttons and then when page loads completely then we change radio input but as not listeners were attached nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is perfectly valid, but if you want to use JQuery I raise you this solution:

```
<div id="hidden_div" class="text-white" >
    <p>ALL RADIOS SELECTED</p>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_radio1">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_radio2">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="group2" id="group2_radio1">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="group2" id="group2_radio2">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // hide the div
        $('#hidden_div').hide();
        // when all radio groups are selected, show the hidden div
        $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
            // get the number of checked radio buttons in each group
            var group1 = $('input[name=group1]:checked').length;
            var group2 = $('input[name=group2]:checked').length;
            // if both groups have a radio button selected, show the div
            if (group1 > 0 && group2 > 0) {
                $('#hidden_div').show();
            }
        });
    });                    
</script>
```

I added some extra radios for my testing, just to double check that any radio works. You had the right idea, but the JQuery implementation wasn't spot on.

I wrote comments on how my solution works but here is a quick recap.

1. Instead of a style to hide the div, do it with JQuery right away
2. When a radio changes, trigger the function
3. Get each radio group and find their length (this lets us know if its selected or not)
4. If the lengths are greater than 1, show it!

Comment: Thank you yes, Jquery seems cleaner and has less code when implemented. I appreciate your answer. I am not looking for the number of radios selected, yet specific radio id's being selected. The answer above is a solution but was hoping for JQuery guidance. Thank you!